# Optimize a simple sorting mysql query to reduce CPU usage

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, amazon-rds, database-performance, database-administration

Below query is taking a very long time to run ( more than 20 seconds) due to sorting which leads to more CPU usage. This is just a straightforward 'select' query with no joins/subqueries. Please let me know if there is an alternate way to sort the data or any way to optimize this query.

SQL:

```
SELECT 
        id, 
        name, 
        part, 
        ACTUAL_SIZE, 
        start, end,
        type, 
        HEADER, 
        CONTENT_SIZE, 
        UPDATE_TS, 
        total, 
        BOUNDARY, 
        SUM,  
        ATM, 
        IND, 
        STATUS, 
        CREATE_TS, 
        ZIP, 
        CLEANUP_TS, 
        YEAR, 
        LAST_YEAR, 
        MIN_DATE,  
        MAX_DATE, 
        ENTRY 
    FROM 
        temp_table 
    WHERE
            id = '12345abcd' 
        AND START >= 0  
        AND END <= 6000
    ORDER BY 
        START, 
        END,
        CREATE_TS ASC
```

The 'order by' clause makes the query to run longer , but we need this sorting to get the proper data

Comment: I would have an index on your 'temp_table' on (id, start, end, create_ts).  This would optimize the query clause AND the order by.  Also, if start and end are numeric values, do not put those criteria filters within 'quotes', just leave as numeric values.

Comment: Hi @DRapp thanks for the reply. Edited it to numeric value as it was a typo. I'll try adding index to all three columns, but is there any other way other than this?

Comment: without an index to help optimize, no.  And from your table name reference of temp_table and knowing if/how that is created too, might be part of your delay issues.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. It will also be helpful to understand whether `START >= 0` or `END <= 6000` is more selective. Which one eliminates more rows from your result set? Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.